# lapply over both group and outcome variable lists in svyby (R)

Tags: r, lapply

I have code to `lapply` a `svyby` function from the `survey` package in r over multiple variables to generate group means and confidence intervals for each variable. My code looks like the following:

```
library(survey)
library(tidyverse)

dem_design <- svydesign(
  ids = ~1, 
  data = na.omit(dplyr::select(data,dv1,dv2,group1,iv1,iv2)) 
) 

dv_variables = c("dv1","dv2")
iv_variables = c("iv1","iv2")

df <- lapply(dv_variables, function(x) svyby(as.formula(paste0("~",x)),
                     by = ~group1 + iv1, 
                     design = dem_design, 
                     FUN = svymean,
                     keep.names = FALSE, vartype = "ci")) %>% bind_rows() %>%  pivot_longer(!c(iv1,group1,ci_l,ci_u),names_to = "dv",values_to = "mean",values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

However, I would now like to modify this code, so that I `lapply` the `iv_variables` variables in the by function. So I would therefore get one final `df` with group means for by group1 + iv1 and group1 + iv2, calculated separately.

I tried the following:

```
df <- lapply(dv_variables, function(x) lapply(iv_variables, function(k)svyby(as.formula(paste0("~",k)),
                  by = ~ as.formula(paste0(k," + group1")), 
              design = dem_design, 
                  FUN = svymean,
                keep.names = FALSE, vartype = "ci"))) %>% bind_rows() %>%  pivot_longer(!c(group1,ci_l,ci_u),names_to = "dv",values_to = "mean",values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

However, this gave me the following error:

```
Error in class(ff) <- "formula" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL
```

How can I `lapply` over both lists to calculate the group means for both and store them in one dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the survey package and without a reproducible example to go by it's hard to say this would fit your purposes but have you tried using `Map()`? It would allow you to cycle through two variables using the following syntax:

```
Map(function(x, y) {

    paste(x,y)

}, x_variables, y_variables)
```

I don't know if this is maybe the source of the problem, but I think there's a syntax error in your second lapply code. `group1` is a variable in your data table, so shouldn't be in quotation marks in the `by` argument. And I think that the first formula argument should call `x` rather than `k`. Here's my suggested modification:

```r
lapply(dv_variables, function(x) 
    lapply(iv_variables, function(k) 

        svyby(as.formula(paste0("~",x)),
             by = as.formula(paste0("~", k, "+", group1)), 
             design = dem_design, 
             FUN = svymean,
             keep.names = FALSE, vartype = "ci"))) %>% 

bind_rows() %>%  
pivot_longer(!c(ci_l,ci_u),names_to = "dv",values_to = "mean",values_drop_na = TRUE)
```

I hope this helps in some way! If not and you're able to provide an example of your data, maybe I can help figure it out.